# Older key as PGP subkey?

Tags: key-derivation, key-size, pgp

Currently I have a 2048-bit PGP key. Suppose I create a new 4096-bit key. Can I add that old key as a subkey of this new one?

Comment: If you are interested in *how* to do it and have further questions, you could ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, PGP allows different-sized subkeys and subkeys are not derived of the main key, so it is possible to have the earlier key be a subkey of the new one.

How to do it is off topic here, but [this](http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Convert_GPG_keys_to_subkeys) should get you started if you use GnuPG.